# Can I access a property of an object containing a list of objects of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, instance-variables

Let's say I have something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, bs):
        self.aname = name
        self.bees = bs
    aname = ''
    bees = []

class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.bname= name
    bname= ''
    def get_aname():
        return aname # can I get this somehow 

aobj = A('name of class A', [B('1'), B('2'), B('3')])

aobj.bees[0].get_aname()  # result should be 'name of class A'
```

Is there any way I could get the name of the class A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aname` is an instance variable. To access this from instances of `B`, you need to pass an instance of `A` to `B` in order for your `B` instance to access `aname`.

But you can't pass an instance of `A` before it's instantiated. Instead, you can define your list of `B` instances and add them as an attribute of `aobj` in a subsequent step:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, bs=None):
        self.aname = name
        self.bees = bs
    aname = ''
    bees = []

class B:
    def __init__(self, name, a_inst):
        self.a_inst = a_inst
        self.bname= name
    bname= ''
    def get_aname(self):
        return self.a_inst.aname

aobj = A('name of class A')
L = [B('1', aobj), B('2', aobj), B('3', aobj)]
aobj.bees = L

aobj.bees[0].get_aname()  # 'name of class A'
```